# Using WCF services remotely

Tags: wcf

I have created a simple WCF service by following a MSDN tutorial. I successfully created service and client. But I have a very basic question, that how can I use this service remotely. Foe example my service is hosted on a web server then how can I access and consume it from my PC. I know how to do this with web services but don't know with WCF service as Iam new to WCF. Any tutorial or code sample is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample you must have specified the address of the service as endpoint.
You just need to modify the address in your app/web.config file and it will start talking to remote service.

See [Specifying an Endpoint Address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Once you deploy the WCF service on some remote server all you have to do is to modify the endpoint address of the client to point to this remote address. This will depend on where you have configured the client endpoint. Usually it is done in the app.config/web.config:

```
<endpoint address="http://someremotedomain/myservice.svc" ...
```